# Copy UI element in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to customize the UIImagePickerController for iPhone right now. I could modify the default buttons (take and cancel) as well as add more buttons.
But I have trouble when attempting to make the customized button look-and-feel like the default iPhone's ones.
At first I think that it'd be possible if I get and then clone the default button as a template for mine by the following code

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:2]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:1]
                            subviews] objectAtIndex:1];


UIButton *anotherButton = [cancelButton copy];
```

But it didnt work due to the fact I have just known lately that NSObject and its subclasses dont implement the protocol NSCopying by default.

I wonder is there any way to either
 - copy an UI element and then modify it as my will
 - create a custom button with the look of Apple's ones

Comment: Irrespective of how you copy it, this code is incredibly fragile.  You are relying on the pattern of views in the hierarchy.  One change to that between OS releases and your app will immediately crash.

Comment: I died a little bit inside when I saw this code.

Comment: I think many of us are a bit - um, how to say this nicely - *horrified* at how you accessed the cancelButton.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this might be a better way:  use `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews` to iterate through all the subviews, look for class UIButton (might be called different), and look for the "cancel" string in the `titleLabel` UILabel.

Comment: Or look for the appropriate selector, since `titleLabel` might be localized.

Comment: @mahboudz `(readonly, copy)` doesn't make sense.  `readonly` means it only generates a getter, so the `copy` directive (which only is used on setters) is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for you guys' comments. I'm still a learner and will take any suggestion to improve my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to duplicate any UIView, put it in a nib file, and load it as many times as you want.

Another alternative is to archive an existing view and then unarchive it.  See the NSKeyedArchiver class.

```
id theButton;  //whatever way you obtain this...
id copyOfTheButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:
                     [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: theButton]];
```

Comment: +1 Using NSCoding to replace NSCopying is so obvious and elegant that I am embarrassed to have overlooked it. This is a very nice solution.

Comment: Well, you should keep in mind that it's not a lightweight approach.  It's appropriate for copying views and the like, but you wouldn't want to use it for large numbers of objects in your model layer, for example.

Comment: Let me also add that archiving and unarchiving is a handy way to put objects on the pasteboard and retrieve them.

Comment: Is this really the best practice means of getting a copy of an object? I understand the mechanism but it seems like a lot of work has to go on under the hood for what seems like relatively simple operation.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There is no easy way to copy an Objective-C object that does not implement `NSCopying`</strike> *(unless you use NSResponder's suggestion of using NSCoding, in which case there is.)* There is `NSCopyObject()`, but this is perhaps the most dangerous function in all of Foundation (see [NSCopyObject() considered harmful](http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439) for my thoughts on this insane function).

Your options are safe or dangerous. The safe way is to just copy the look and feel of the element in your own code. This is tedious, but generally achievable. The dangerous way is to reverse engineer the element's class and interface and try to create your own instance (with alloc/init). This might work and it might not, and it may break between versions of the OS, but it may give you better results, faster. Personally, I tend towards just recreating the original element by hand as best you can. Generally Photoshop is an important part of that work.